# Multi tenancy confusion

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, multi-tenant

I have configured multi tenancy with hibernate using `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` and `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver`. I have also written a filter which intercepts the url and decided the who is the tenant.

I have several questions/confusions.

1. This design means every url has to carry the tenant id with it(may be in the form of domain/subdomain), right ? what if it doesn't carry it? How to handle such corner cases?
2. Is this approach a proper one? I also thought about storing tenant id in user session but I thought it is not a good idea. (In past I have faced issues while storing something in session and it has its limitations for certain scenarios).

   I am confused between these two approaches, is there any third approach please suggest. I have opted for `SCHEMA` strategy of hibernate for multi tenancy.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement Multi-Tenancy design is to have Tenant_ID in every transaction table and one master table to store Tenant information.

With every request we need to send tenant_id. 
If you have default tenant requirement where if no tenant_id comes data should get inserted you can implement that behavior. 
You can't insert one tenant data in another tenant, so tenant_id is mandatory and proper validation should be there for Tenant_ID.

Comment: Do you mean to say I should have tenantID in each table as a separate column ?

Comment: Yes, without Tenant_id you can't distinct which row data belongs to which Tenant. i hope this helps.

Comment: There are multiple strategy for implementing multi tenancy, the one you specified, there are two more, 1. is Schema based separate schema for each tenant and 2. Separate database for each tenant, I am using the SCHEMA based strategy.